# How can I debug battery-unplugged function in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios

I make **battery control program**.
And I need to confirm function that **battery control** when **battery unplugged**.

I want get status that **full**, **charging**, **unplugged**, and *unknown*.

In *debugging*, I can see **status** that full and **charging**, because *I connect iPad and Mac in USB*.

If I **disconnect usb**, then *I cannot debug*.

How can I debug **battery** when **unplugged**?

Comment: I guess there is a wireless debugging too for that you will not need any USB to run the app into device. Also use charger for charging the device instead of connecting it with USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an apple documentation for wireless debugging: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devbc48d1bad

Steps to set up iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

1. Choose Window > Devices and Simulators, then in the window that
   appears, click Devices.
2. Connect your device to your Mac with a
       Lightning cable.
3. Check if passcode enables in your device settings.
4. Enable if not already enabled. In the left column, select the
           device, and in the detail area, select Connect via network.

Comment: Please vote to close as duplicate when it's something simple, thank you. :)